# how to copy from one variable to another using if condition in spss

Tags: spss

I am looking for IF condition syntax in SPSS. I have 2 variables, one is IND and the other is code:

```
IND (String)             Code (String)        i want final var as below

retail                                        retail
finance                  5411                 5411
education                -                    education 
transportation           4491                 4491 
consulting               8711                 8711
insurance                -                    insurance
finance                  -                    finance
other                    4813                 4813
```

Both are string variables. Wherever code is blank, I want data from the IND variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `do if` structure. See example code added:

```
string final_var (a50).

do if code = "0000" or code = "".
comp final_var = ind.
else.
comp final_var = code.
end if.

exe.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Dihurio...This helps a lot...I need one more clarification. In code varriable I have sysmis also. How to replace them with Ind.

Comment: I assume code is a string variable and I assume you mean code variable to be empty for some cases (instead of sysmis, string variable can not be system missing). I have made an update for the syntax in the answer.